# return function value inside conditional statement

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I have a function with arguments,
inside the function, I have if statements. When I try to execute the function. It only works when the if statement is true, it does not work if statement is false.

Everything works fine if I don't be a fancy pants to use a function. 
But, I want to improve my code, not to repeat myself 10 times.

```
function PopUpWithText(popUp_img, popUp_txt, popUp_icon) {
  var hotspotScale = 1;
  if (hotspotScale === 1) {
    popUp_img.setAttribute("scale", "0");
    popUp_txt.setAttribute("scale", "0");
    popUp_icon.setAttribute("scale", "0");
    hotspotScale = 0;
  } else if (hotspotScale === 0) {
    popUp_img.setAttribute("scale", "1");
    popUp_txt.setAttribute("scale", "1");
    popUp_icon.setAttribute("scale", "1");
    hotspotScale = 1;
  }
}

var popUpWithText1 = document.querySelectorAll("#popUp_icon1, #AButton");
for (var i = 0; i < popUpWithText1.length; i++) {
  popUpWithText1[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    PopUpWithText(
      document.querySelector("#popUp_img1"),
      document.querySelector("#popUp_txt1"),
      document.querySelector("#popUp_icon1")
    );
  });
}
```

First, I know i am definitely missing a `return`. Secondly, this piece of code is supposed to toggle the scale between value 0 & 1. I can change the scale value to 0, but then it does not toggle back to value 1.  Please help

Comment: You are setting `hotspotScale = 1` every time you call the function so it'll never hit your false clause. Trying moving `var hotspotScale = 1` to the global scope (outside the function) if you are trying to toggle back and forth.

Comment: you set `hotspotScale` to 1 at the beginning of every function call, so the first `if` is always true, and the `else if` won't ever be called. even though you set `hotspotScale = 0;` in the `elseif`, this doesn't persist to the next time you call the function

Comment: You're setting `hotspotscale` to 1 right at the start of the function - this happens every time it runs. Just remove that line, and move it outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `PopUpWithText` you are setting `hotspotScale = 1`, so your code will never take the `else if` branch. You can move that to a global variable outside of the function scope.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to switch visibility on the elements, you can use the `visible` attribute:

```
function PopUpWithText(popUp_img, popUp_txt, popUp_icon) {
  let visible = popUp_img.getAttribute('visible')
  popUp_img.setAttribute("visible", !visible);
  popUp_txt.setAttribute("visible", !visible);
  popUp_icon.setAttribute("visible", !visible);
}
```

To make things easier, You can throw your elements to a parent entity:

```
<a-entity id="parent">
  <!-- All three elements --!>
</a-entity>
```

and If you want to change scales, you can do a similar switch:

```
function PopUpWithText(popUp_parent) {
  let scale = popUp_parent.getAttribute('scale')
  scale = scale.x === "1" ? "0" : "1" 
  popUp_parent.setAttribute("scale", scale);
}
```

Like i did in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/by9tusgz/) fiddle.